# "Unspecified error. Function is not implemented" error in OpenCV in Pycharm IDE

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm

```
cv2.imshow("VIDEO", frame)
```

> cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:632:
>   error: (-2:Unspecified error)  The function is not implemented.
>   Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you
>   are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then
>   re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvShowImage'

PLEASE HELP!!

Comment: The error message contains an explanation of what's wrong. OpenCV contains many parts, and a specific build typically don't contain every single feature. This could be to save space, because of licencing problems, or because they rely on some other shared library. Which operating system are you using? Did you build cv2 yourself, or how did you install it?

Comment: Please don't shout **PLEASE HELP!!**